# activestate perl windows - find all installed xs modules

Tags: windows, perl, activestate, xs

For prepairing a perl upgrade, i wanted to know which [perl xs modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XS_%28Perl%29) are installed for my local activestate perl 5.16 installation.

Does anybody know how i could get such a list of perl modules?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how easy it is to properly differentiate between 'installed packages' and 'installed XS packages'.

The latter will very likely have been installed via PPM, so you should be able to list them with `ppm list`.

Comment: Have tried that before, but "PPM list" shows all installed modules and does not differerntiate between "normal" and XS packages.

Comment: I'm not honestly sure that perl differentiates in 'normal operation'. I suspect you'll be needing to look at the module installation to see.

Answer (score 0):

`dir /s/b *.dll` from your AP's `lib` and `site\lib` directory. (I think those in `lib` came with AP, and those in `site\lib` were installed afterwards.)